# Android XML - How to achieve this "step bar" on layout

Tags: android, xml

I am doing a register Module that has two steps (Fragments) and i want to have this kind of "Step bar" that indicates where are you. Any idea of how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by using a `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
  style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:max="100"
  android:progress="50"/>
```

Comment: Oh, didnt know about that native style. Thanks!